# Dropdown mobile don't work after WP update

Tags: dropdown, mobile

I've updated my WP site and the drop down menu don't work in mobile device.

After the update also on the desktop device I've problems but I've fixed. Now remains only the mobile.

The site is [taras706ac.it](https://www.taras706ac.it/)

I've tried to extend this CSS line to mm-trigger:active (before has set only on mm-trigger:hover):

`.mm-trigger:hover, .mm-trigger:active {
        background-color:#FAFAFA;
        color:#666666;
}`

but not resolve my issue

If you need further informations, please add comment.

My WP version is 6.0.5